# printing the elements by removing middle element of stack

Tags: java, stack

Input: First line of input contains a single integer T which denotes the number of test cases. T test cases follows, first line of each test case contains a integer n. Second line consists of n spaced integers.

Output: Print the elements of the stack after deleting the middle element in  reverse order.

Input:1

7

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

output is:

> 7 6 5 3 2 1

actually i am able to do printing in reverse fashion but i don't know how to remove middle element from the stack.please help

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class GFG
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    int test=s.nextInt();
    for(int t=0;t<test;t++)
    {
        int n=s.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            a[i]=s.nextInt();
        Stack<Integer> stack=new Stack<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
             stack.push(a[i]);
        }
       ListIterator<Integer> lstIterator=stack.listIterator(stack.size());
       while(lstIterator.hasPrevious())
       {
           Integer res=lstIterator.previous();
           //what condition should i give so that it would print all the 
           elements except middle one.
           System.out.print(res+" ");   
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you deal with middle element in case there are even number of elements?

Comment: for that situation i will check for if n is even or odd and if it is even then i  will delete the (n/2)-1 position as per the test case.for eg-n=6 and element is 1 2 3 4 5 6 then my output will be 6 5 4 2 1

Comment: kindly tell me the logic to delete the middle element for the odd no.of elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not insert the middle element of input array.

get the middle element index :

```
 int middle = a.length/2;
```

do not push the middle element in the stack:

```
Stack<Integer> stack=new Stack<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(i != middle)
      stack.push(a[i]);
}
```

Everything else looks okay. Just make sure to provide meaningful names to variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with using `pop()` method popping returns and removes the top element of the stack so that way you can create and fill a new stack with reverse order, don't need to reverse the iterator, have a look at the code below.

```
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

class GFG {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Define stacks here
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> new_stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    int test = s.nextInt();
    for (int t = 0; t < test; t++) {
      int n = s.nextInt();
      int a[] = new int[n];
      double middle = Math.ceil((double) n / 2);
      System.out.println("Middle is : " + middle);
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = s.nextInt();
      }

      // add elements to stack

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        stack.push(a[i]);
      }

      //popping the elements of stack

      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        Integer element = stack.pop();
        if (j != middle -1) {
          new_stack.push(element);
        }
      }

      ListIterator<Integer> lstIterator = new_stack.listIterator(stack.size());
      while (lstIterator.hasNext()) {
        Integer res = lstIterator.next();
//what condition should i give so that it would print all the elements except middle one.
        System.out.print(res + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use recursion to delete the middle element of the stack.

- current = 0
- mid = stack.size()/2

  ```
   static void delete(Stack<Integer> stack, int current, int mid){

      if(stack.isEmpty())
         return;

      if(current == mid){
         stack.pop();
         return;
      }

      int x = stack.pop();
      current++;
      delete(stack, current, mid);
      stack.push(x);
     }
  ```